# How can I add an event to chart.js legend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, legend, chart.js

Based on [this post](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1768) I've been able to add the event, but it's not triggered. Any idea why? I'm using the default chart.js legend.

```
Chart.helpers.each(vm.chart.legend.legendItems, function(legendNode, index) {
  Chart.helpers.addEvent(legendNode, 'mouseover', function() {
    console.log('event triggered!');
  });
});
```

[image: alt]

**Brief code description**: Adds the event to every legend item.

**Using**: angularjs and chartjs 2.1.6

Answer (score 0):

I've got [this answer](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2898) from one of the developers. Currently it's not possible to add custom events to the canvas legend. You must create you own html legend using myChartInstance.generateLegend().

I've opened a request. I will update if they add this event natively.

Comment: What did you do instead? How did you add the event on the generateLegend? I am trying to add the event (onHover) for my generateLegend to focus the pie chart but not sure how to do it.